# img[::a,::b] can reduce resolution of image in PIL，but why

Tags: python-3.x

img[::a,::b] can reduce resolution of image in PIL，but why?
img[::a, ::b] resolution or size is x and y then you will get image which is x/a ,y/b
who knows why or how?

Comment: What? If you downsample by `a` and `b` bidirectionally then yes, it can only decrease resolution. `[::a]` means "give me every a-th member of the collection". You should really consider rephrasing this question as well. WHat are you trying to solve or do?

Comment: thanks,I try to decrease resolution, and I see someone use this to decrease resolution, but I don't understand why it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the syntax for a multi-dimensional slice. The result includes every `a`th pixel along the x-axis and every `b`th pixel along the y-axis.

Slice notation is not too difficult to understand. It looks like `start:stop:step`, where any of the values can be omitted to get a default. If you're omitting `step` at the end, the second colon is not required (you can just write `start:stop`). Slice notation is only allowed when indexing (e.g. `foo[start:stop:step]`). To make a slice outside that context, you can call the `slice` constructor (though you may need to pass `None` for omitted values rather than just skipping them).

The default `step` value is 1. The default `start` and `stop` depend on the sign of `step`. If `step` is positive, then `start`'s default is `0` and `stop`'s is the size of the object being sliced. If `step` is negative, `start` will default to one less than the size of the object (the largest valid index) and `stop` will default to an index "just before the first value" (this is not `-1` as you might expect, because negative indexes wrap around to the end; the only way you could specify the index normally is `-len(...)-1`).

Not all Python objects allow multi-dimensional indexing (where the index is a tuple of indexes or slices). Normal lists don't support it (not even if they're nested). The PIL image does however, probably because it is replicating the behavior of a `numpy` multi-dimensional array.